# Resample python list with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

Fairly new to python and pandas here.

I make a query that's giving me back a timeseries. I'm never sure how many data points I receive from the query (run for a single day), but what I do know is that I need to resample them to contain 24 points (one for each hour in the day).

Printing m3hstream gives

```
[(1479218009000L, 109), (1479287368000L, 84)]
```

Then I try to make a dataframe df with

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = list(m3hstream), columns=['Timestamp', 'Value'])
```

and this gives me an output of

```
          Timestamp  Value
       0  1479218009000    109
       1  1479287368000     84
```

Following I do this

```
 daily_summary = pd.DataFrame()
 daily_summary['value'] = df['Value'].resample('H').mean()
 daily_summary = daily_summary.truncate(before=start, after=end)
 print "Now daily summary"
 print daily_summary
```

But this is giving me a TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Could anyone please let me know how to resample it so I have 1 point for each hour in the 24 hour period that I'm querying for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First thing you need to do is convert that `'Timestamp'` to an actual `pd.Timestamp`.  It looks like those are `milliseconds`
- Then `resample` with the `on` parameter set to `'Timestamp'`

---

```
df = df.assign(
    Timestamp=pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, unit='ms')
).resample('H', on='Timestamp').mean().reset_index()

             Timestamp  Value
0  2016-11-15 13:00:00  109.0
1  2016-11-15 14:00:00    NaN
2  2016-11-15 15:00:00    NaN
3  2016-11-15 16:00:00    NaN
4  2016-11-15 17:00:00    NaN
5  2016-11-15 18:00:00    NaN
6  2016-11-15 19:00:00    NaN
7  2016-11-15 20:00:00    NaN
8  2016-11-15 21:00:00    NaN
9  2016-11-15 22:00:00    NaN
10 2016-11-15 23:00:00    NaN
11 2016-11-16 00:00:00    NaN
12 2016-11-16 01:00:00    NaN
13 2016-11-16 02:00:00    NaN
14 2016-11-16 03:00:00    NaN
15 2016-11-16 04:00:00    NaN
16 2016-11-16 05:00:00    NaN
17 2016-11-16 06:00:00    NaN
18 2016-11-16 07:00:00    NaN
19 2016-11-16 08:00:00    NaN
20 2016-11-16 09:00:00   84.0
```

If you want to fill those `NaN` values, use `ffill`, `bfill`, or `interpolate`

```
df.assign(
    Timestamp=pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, unit='ms')
).resample('H', on='Timestamp').mean().reset_index().interpolate()

             Timestamp   Value
0  2016-11-15 13:00:00  109.00
1  2016-11-15 14:00:00  107.75
2  2016-11-15 15:00:00  106.50
3  2016-11-15 16:00:00  105.25
4  2016-11-15 17:00:00  104.00
5  2016-11-15 18:00:00  102.75
6  2016-11-15 19:00:00  101.50
7  2016-11-15 20:00:00  100.25
8  2016-11-15 21:00:00   99.00
9  2016-11-15 22:00:00   97.75
10 2016-11-15 23:00:00   96.50
11 2016-11-16 00:00:00   95.25
12 2016-11-16 01:00:00   94.00
13 2016-11-16 02:00:00   92.75
14 2016-11-16 03:00:00   91.50
15 2016-11-16 04:00:00   90.25
16 2016-11-16 05:00:00   89.00
17 2016-11-16 06:00:00   87.75
18 2016-11-16 07:00:00   86.50
19 2016-11-16 08:00:00   85.25
20 2016-11-16 09:00:00   84.00
```

Comment: I ran your code and it's giving me the same output that I posted in the question. Am I doing something else wrong maybe?

Comment: If you aren't getting exactly what I've posted as my out put, then something is wrong.  Where are you running this?  In an iPython/Jupyter notebook?  iPython?  Console?

Comment: Console. I'm using the PyCharm IDE and this is printed output in console.

Comment: Are you running this then afterwards printing `df`?  Or are you assigning this back to `df` and then printing `df`?

Comment: It's basically your code followed by a print df. But it's in the same method. So I think the latter of the two options.

Comment: You assumed that the operation altered `df`.  it did not, you have to assign it  back to the `df` variable.

Comment: This is a different dataframe.  When I answer questions, I tend not to assume that OP wants to clobber their existing dataframes, so I produce a new one with `df.assign`.  Now that we've cleared that up, you should be good to go.

Comment: I got the same output now, thanks. About the NaNs, doesn't the .mean imply they will have the mean value of the two datapoints?

Comment: No.  It will produce the mean for all values within the hour.... I'll add more to the answer

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try:

```
daily_summary = daily_summary.set_index('Timestamp')

daily_summary.index = pd.to_datetime(daily_summary.index, unit='ms')
```

For once an hour:

```
daily_summary.resample('H').mean()
```

or for once a day:

```
daily_summary.resample('D').mean()
```

Comment: This is the output:

                            Value
Timestamp                        
1970-01-01 00:24:39.218009    109
1970-01-01 00:24:39.287368     84

Comment: @little.toblerone added the units='ms' to to_datetime